# Can't get data from https request c#

Tags: c#, ssl, asp.net-web-api, https, ssl-certificate

I have installed server certificate in IIS with binding and have controller with methods example below:

```
    [HttpPost("checkOrder")]
    [RequireHttps]
    public void CheckOrder(CommonParamsJson inputParams)
    {
        var tmp = new YaMoneyCommonHttpProtocol("checkOrder", new Settings());
        tmp.ProcessRequest(inputParams);
    }
```

after request to this method server get his but appear exception:

microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel[17] connection id bad request data: "invalid request line: ....

and

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.BadHttpRequestException: Invalidrequest line ...
[image]

How i understand not happening handshake action

Comment: `but appear exception:` What is the url you are hitting that throws that exception? Please include a screenshot of the exception.

Comment: How are you posting to the `CheckOrder` endpoint?

Comment: @mjwills this request send Yandex Api

Comment: @mjwills but it true request route

Comment: Perhaps you'll find your answer here: https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/969

Comment: @RuardvanElburg i have a question, in iis i made data binding for ssl in 443 port, in launchSettings.json should be specify same port and applicationUrl should be https://... not http://...?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg Thanks a lot, your answer helped me solve this problem)